# Mount On/To A Cardboard

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

I have a question about the verb "*mount*":

> 1. The picture is ***mounted on*** a cardboard.
> 2. The picture is ***mounted to*** a cardboard.

Are "*on*" and "*to*" different?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same. "mounted to" might imply to some readers that it was *more permanently* mounted than "mounted on" does. To clearly affirm, rather than imply such permanence, I would try "affixed to", "attached to" or "glued to".

However, in AmE, "cardboard" is not a count noun, so it would not be "a cardboard", it would be said:

- Mounted {on/to} **cardboard**
  or
- Mounted {on/to}  **a piece of cardboard**